# JSTL forEach not working in custom tag

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl, el

**My class:**

```
public class CustomObject {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

**Request:**

```
List<CustomObject> items = new ArrayList<CustomObject>();
items.add(new CustomObject());
request.setAttribute( "items", items );
```

**This example is working in my jsp:**

```
<div class="container">
    <c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
      ${item.name}
    </c:forEach>
```

**But when I use the custom tag is returning the error. Why doesn't read the property?**

```
<%@ attribute name="list" required="true" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:if test="${!empty list}">
   <c:forEach var="item" items="${list}">
        <li><c:out value="${item.name}"/></li>
    </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

**Console:**

> Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class
>   'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'name'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the attribute type, without it specified the `list` attributes type defaults to `String`:

`<%@ attribute name="list" required="true" type="java.util.List"  %>`

Comment: Could you be more specific? If you are concerned about type safety I am not sure why you are using jstl

Comment: I was just wondering if it would be possible to specify the class being used in the attribute so I don't have to remember changing it inside a jsp when I rename it, but then I realized you specify only the collection type that belongs to java sdk, in that case you wll never rename it (dohhhhh). Forget what I said.